# How could I activate Bluetooth in Juno? (Asus Pro P550L)

Tags: release-juno, bluetooth, laptop

My name is Marco and I am a new fan of elementary OS ([release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno)).
I installed it in an Asus Pro P550L. I have a problem with Bluetooth. I would like to activate it but I don't know how. Someone could help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please execute this command in your terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install switchboard-plug-bluetooth
```

Comment: Hasan thank's for your answer but then I wrote the command I read "impossible to find the packet switchboard-plug-bluethoot "

What can I do?

Comment: Please copy paste the command, I can see that you have spelled `bluetooth` wrong. Please type in the right one and let me know.